# segregation based on id in kdb q

Tags: kdb

I have a table

| ID | Course | Seats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CS | 50 |
| 1 | EC | 60 |
| 1 | ME | 30 |
| 2 | CS | 60 |
| 2 | EC | 40 |
| 2 | ME | 25 |
| 2 | EE | 20 |

I need to segregate based on the ID and get a table like

| ID | Course | Seats | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CS | 50 | A |
| 1 | EC | 60 | A |
| 1 | ME | 30 | A |
| 2 | CS | 60 | B |
| 2 | EC | 40 | B |
| 2 | ME | 25 | B |
| 2 | EE | 20 | B |

the ID column is of type C (character string).
How to achieve the above table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you intend to assign arbitrary group names of unknown amount or specifically chosen group names of known amounts? If specifically chosen and the amount is known, then you would use a dictionary as Cathal suggested.

If the number of groups is known to be less than say 26 you could assign the alphabet:

```
update Group:.Q.A[-1+ID]from t
```

If the number is larger than 26 but known to be less than 26^n then you can generate random groupnames of appropriate length (in this example length n=3)

```
q)update Group:{string@[neg[count distinct x]?`3;-1+x]}[ID]from t
ID Course Seats Group
---------------------
1  CS     50    "enf"
1  EC     60    "enf"
1  ME     30    "enf"
2  CS     60    "plh"
2  EC     40    "plh"
2  ME     25    "plh"
2  EE     20    "plh"
```

If the number of groups is completely arbitrary then the only way to ensure uniquely assigned group "names" would be to assign guids but at that point you'd be better off using the IDs themselves as the identifier.

Answer (score 4):

One method:

```
q)update Group:(1 2!"AB")ID from t
ID Course Seats Group
---------------------
1  CS     50    A
1  EC     60    A
1  ME     30    A
2  CS     60    B
2  EC     40    B
2  ME     25    B
2  EE     20    B
```